# Converting two 8 bit values to 16 bit unsigned int and back in lua

Tags: lua, type-conversion

I'm having trouble converting to 16 bit int values from raw data I'm receiving over Ethernet.

For example, I might receive this:
\x00\x0A\x00\x00\x00\x09\x01\x10\x00\x01\x00\x10\x02\x00\x00

I need to take two of these raw data bytes and convert them to a 16 bit unsigned value.
So far I've tried with tonumber() but I can't find a way to make it combine the 2 bytes, I've seen some examples of using string.gsub() on here to do the conversions but these all deal with an an ASCII representation of the raw data.

TIA

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I ended up going with the solution posted by @Joseph as it was a bit simpler looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.byte()` on a single character to turn it into its numerical value, then just multiply the more significant one by 256 (or if you're on Lua 5.3 or newer, shift it left by 8 bits), then add them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Lua 5.3 or newer, try also `string.unpack`. You can select the byte order with `<` and `>`:

```
s="\x00\x0A\x00\x00\x00\x09\x01\x10\x00\x01\x00\x10\x02\x00\x00\x00"
print("<",">")
for i=1,#s,2 do
    print((string.unpack("<i2",s,i)),(string.unpack(">i2",s,i)))
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now that I've seen string.unpack used I'm go to have a play around with it later, cheers.